# using static member of a class in .cpp file

Tags: c++, class, static, fatal-error

I created a class, and in the public section, I declared on the following:

```
static int num;
```

and in the constructor, which is in the same .h file, I did:

```
num++;
```

Up to now everything works fine.

The problem is, that the implementation of my destructor is in the .cpp, I wrote:

```
num--;
```

But visual won't let me do it. It shouts:

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Any help?

Comment: To counter your question: any code? Also: did you **define** (not **declare**) that static member? Are you using any book?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your static variable in the *.cpp file. This is usually done at the top. For example:

```
// in the *.h file
class MyClass
{
    public:
        static int num;
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
};

// in the *.cpp file
int MyClass::num = 0;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    MyClass::num++;
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    MyClass::num--;
}
```